# If $\cos 27^\circ=0.89$, then how much is $\csc 27^\circ$?

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I came across this problem and can't seem to solve it:

> Given the approximation $\cos 27^\circ = 0.89$ use trigonometric identities to find the value of $\csc 27^\circ$

If someone could explain the process to solve this problem, it would help me greatly.

Comment: Hint: Draw a right triangle with hypotenuse $1$ and one angle $27^{\circ}$. A cosecant is a ratio of sides; can you fill in the remaining sides using the given information and then compute the ratio?

Answer (score 1):

$csc(27) = \frac{1}{sin(27)} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-cos^2(27)}}$ using basic trig identities.